# Is it bad practice to pass props through multiple components down to a child?

Tags: reactjs

Is it bad practice / will it hurt performance if I pass props from a root component down to a child component 4-5 components down often?

Im thinking every component in the chain will have to rerender every time the props change, meaning bad performance, since its only a small child component inside the large component which actually needs to change.

If this is indeed the case, should I flatten my root component, or should I implement a custom 'shouldComponentUpdate', or something else?

Comment: It should be fine to pass it down 4-5 components because react's render resolution is very fast. Since each child component won't actually require a dom modification, you should not see a performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` is very good practice to minimize re-rendering, especially if the components are kept simple and small to be able to define the `shouldComponentUpdate` simple as well.

As an alternative, look into `react-redux` or other state container to manage state easier without much hassle.

Answer (score 2):

The need should be rare, but React's diff-ing algorithm will ensure nothing updates unless it is necessary. Performance should not suffer.

For instance, I usually start my apps with a container class which does a media query (using `react-responsive`). Using this media query I pass either `display="desktop"` or `display="mobile"` as a prop down the next component. I usually pass `this.props.display` all the way down my component tree and it is the deciding factor in how my CSS looks (either the desktop view or the mobile view). In this case, performance is actually enhanced!

Answer (score 1):

React won't re-render the DOM unless the tree actually requires an update/change therefore no rendering performance costs.

You can also use shouldComponentUpdate() to manage your updates to each component.

[Facebook's React Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)

[shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate)